# How to create a uniform structured array in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I could create the following strucutured array in numpy:

```py
dt = np.dtype([('n', 'i4'),('x', 'f8'), ('y', 'f8'), ('z', 'f8')])
arr = np.array((1, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0))
```

This creates the array:

```
array((1, 5., 6., 7.), dtype=[('n', '<i4'), ('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8'), ('z', '<f8')])
```

In `dt` the last three columns are all floats `f8` is there a shorter way to declare `dt` when there are multiple consecutive columns of the same type?

Comment: `dt = np.dtype([('n', 'i4'), *zip('xyz', ['f8']*3)])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not faster, but you can create an helper function to generate dtype:

```
def gen_dtype(names, override=None, default='f8'):
    d = dict(zip(names, [default]*len(names)))
    d.update(override)
    return np.dtype(list(d.items()))

dt  = gen_dtype(list('nxyz'), {'n': 'i4'})
```

Output:

```
>>> dt
dtype([('n', '<i4'), ('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8'), ('z', '<f8')])
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method is to use the dictionary format to define the dtype:

```
dt2 = np.dtype( {'names': ['n','x','y','z'],
                 'formats': ['i4'] + ['f8']*3} )
```